# How to set variables using existing xml file in installShield 2010

Tags: installshield

I build an installer with Basic MSI Project in InstallShield 2010.

My setup has custom dialogs with inputs like textBoxes. Each TextBox has associated a variable with a default value. The package kit contain also an .xml file wich is generated by installer and has in it the values setted in wizard in a specific path. That works very well.

The problem is I have a lot of this textBoxes and a lot of steps. I want to add the possibility for a user to browse an .xml file in one of the wizard's steps and then skip all the steps to insert data in textboxes.

I guess that inside my installer's project I have to set the default values for each variables with a value or with a path (I know exactly where the value I need is in xml) in condition that the user points to an xml.

I will ignore for now if the browsed xml has not the same template I need, let's say that I will find the paths.

The question is how I set the variables in my project in case that xml file is browsed?

**Latest edit:**

my xml looks like:

```
<Settings>
    <SiteNames>
        <Setting property="prop1">value1</Setting>
        <Setting property="prop2">value2</Setting>
    </SiteNames>
</Settings>
```

and my .js is:

```
function setValues(){
    var xmlPath = Session.Property("IS_BROWSE_FILEBROWSED");
    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");

    xmlDoc.async = "false";
    xmlDoc.load(xmlPath);

    var elem = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Setting");
    for (var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
        Session.Property(elem[i].getAttribute("property")) = elem[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
}
```

It is something wrong? my property values are not changing..

The script is running when a button is pressed. I don't know what I have to do for this to work.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up with jscript function.. it didn't work.. I don't know why.

I use vbScript instead (is my first time :) I use vbscripts)

```
Dim xmlPath  
Dim xmlDoc
xmlPath = Session.Property("IS_BROWSE_FILEBROWSED")
set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.async = "false"
xmlDoc.load(xmlPath)    

for each x in xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Setting")           
    Session.Property(x.getAttribute("property")) = x.text
next
```

It works very well!
Thanks for guiding me Christipher Painter!

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom action that can use an XML DOM to read the XML file and call MsiSetProperty() to set your various properties.

For example:

```
<Settings>
  <Setting Id="SOMEPROP1">SOMEVALUE</Setting>
  <Setting Id="SOMEPROP2">SOMEVALUE</Setting>
</Setting>
```

Then it's just a matter of (pseudo code)

```
for each Setting element in Settings
  MsiSetProperty( setting.ID, setting.InnerText )
next
```

Also MSI's internal native UI only has a directory browser not a file browser control so you will either have to keep the filename a constant and browse the directory or work the file selection control into your custom action also.

Comment: you say that <Settings>
  <Setting Id="SOMEPROP1">SOMEVALUE</Setting>
  <Setting Id="SOMEPROP2">SOMEVALUE</Setting>
</Setting> is my xml file? and inside my custom action I have to put for each Settings.....? where should I write the link between xml and my custom action? and what type of custom action should I select? is about Set Property?

Comment: The type of custom action depends on what you write it in.  You could write it in InstallScript, C++, VBScript, C# et al.   When you implement your file selection dialog you'll have to pass that filepath off to your XML Document Object Model which will be then used to do your query for Setting elements.  In InstallScript and C++ you'll use MsiSetProperty(hMSI, PROPNAME, PROPVALUE), in VBScript you'll use Session.Property(PROPNAME)=PROPVALUE and in C#(DTF) it's Session[PROPNAME]=PROPVALUE

Comment: I'm not handle it...I didn't write for now another custom action than lunch an exe file. I don't know what libraries should I include in script or what functions should I use. Should I send the path of xml through a parameter? Sorry for that, can you give me a more specific example?

Comment: I mention that I create a dialog with a file browser. for those who need it, here is a link with the steps: http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield16helplib_sp1/FileOpenDialog-HowTo.htm